# how to select last json data

Tags: flutter, dart

In here i want to make a condition if the dropdown box select the last option it will show new box but i don't know how to make that condition. What i use now is the condition where the option is "Other Impression" selected but the api has 2 language so i cannot hard code the condition. Maybe i think it's like `dropdownOption.lastIndexOf` .... i don't know

This is the Json

```
List dummyDropdownOption = [
{
  "value": 1,
  "label": "Sistem Kemudi otomatis dapat diandalkan",
},
{
  "value": 2,
  "label": "Mobilitas tanpa awak mematuhi rambu dan aturan lalu lintas",
},
{
  "value": 3,
  "label": "Mobilitas tanpa awak memiliki kondisi kebersihan yang baik.",
},
{
  "value": 4,
  "label": "Other impressions",
    }, 
];
```

The condition i use for now

```
(dropdownValue1 == 'Other impressions')
                  ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dart, you also have a `last` property on the `List`. [Doc](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/List/last.html)

```dart
void main() {
  print(dummyDropdownOption.last);
}
```

#### Console log

```
{value: 4, label: Other impressions}
```

Comment: well i think it's more efficient and this is what i was looking, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get last index item like below.

```dart
dummyDropdownOption[dummyDropdownOption.length - 1]
```

Comment: well it works but something weird is happend, i use 2 language one english and other is indonesian everything is fine but if i use this dummyDropdownOption[dummyDropdownOption.length - 1] 
it will only get the english option but if i print the value it print indonesian option.

Comment: can we just make it to if last option selected ?

Comment: my fault, i still testing the dummy json but i expect the real json lol

Comment: Oh, I missed the `.last` getter. Thierry's answer is better then it.